# All values converted to strings when reading csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I've got a CSV file (https://easyupload.io/fehzj5) that I must analyse in python.
To work with the data, I'm converting it to a list of lists:

```
import csv


def read_dataset(file):
    rows = []
    with open(file, 'r') as csvfile:
        csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        for row in csvreader:
            rows.append(row)
    return rows
```

The CSV file consists entirely of floats, which I double-checked by opening the file in a text editor.
However, whenever I call a value from the output of `read_dataset`, it is always of type float.

e.g.
[image]

I assume the problem is in my `read_dataset`code somewhere. Any help much appreciated!

Comment: I recommend that you analyze with something more focused than nested lists.  PANDAS might be a good choice.

Comment: Sidenotes: 1) `delimiter` defaults to `','`, so you don't need to specify it. 2) You can simplify down to `return list(csvreader)` instead of using `rows`.

Answer (score 4):

The numeric data in the CSV file is stored as a string. There is no "convert to string" operation happening here because the data is already a string. `csv.reader()` has no way to know what cells are numeric, so it won't convert anything to a float. You will need to do that yourself.

Comment: Actually `csv.reader()` does have a way to know what cells are numeric.  There's a `quoting` flag that can indicate non-quoted fields are float.  Since the OP's data is all floats, that works.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I am unfamiliar with this parameter. Thanks for pointing it out! Maybe it would be more accurate to say something like "The reader instance you create here is dumb and doesn't know which cells are floats."

Answer (score 2):

You can use the pandas method [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) then specify the data type of your headers as float, then convert the dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def read_dataset(file):    
    dtype_data = {'col1': np.float64, 'col2': np.float64}
    df = pd.read_csv(file, delimiter=",", dtype=dtype_data)
    return df
```

Comment: You don't even need to specify the dtypes necessarily. If the values look like floats, they'll be converted automatically. Also `delimiter` defaults to `','`, so you don't need to specify it.

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC):

> `csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC`
> Instructs `writer` objects to quote all non-numeric fields.
>
> Instructs the reader to convert all non-quoted fields to type float.

Since your sample data is all non-quoted floating point:

```py
import csv

with open('downloads/stackoverflow_data.csv') as csvfile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile,quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
    rows = list(csvreader)

print(rows[0][:10])
```

Output:

```
[693.366, 692.038, 690.964, 690.964, 689.796, 687.634, 686.228, 685.072, 685.072, 683.856]
```